# passing a struct array as argument to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I am trying to print this out but it keeps failing, and prints the just the address, I"m new to C and not quite sure how to fix this.

I have two struct and two methods,

```
struct Date {
    char week_day[30];
    int day[31];
    int month[12];
};

struct Holiday {
    char name[80]; //name
    struct Date date; //date
};


void printHols(struct Holiday hol[]){
    printf("Holidays in 2018\n");

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        printf("%d / %d \t - %s \t - %s", hol[i].date.day, hol[i].date.month, hol[i].date.week_day, hol[i].name);
    }
}

void holidaysValues(){
    struct Holiday holiday={{"New Year",{"Monday",1,1}}, {"Some Holiday",{"Tuesday",2,3}} };

//passing this struct below  doesn't work as expected, prints addresses of how[I].date.day, hol[I].date.month

    printHols(&holiday);
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: enable warning will help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed your code a bit.

First of all, I'm sure you meant to use ints for day and month not arrays of them. 
And you forgot to add [] to holiday.
And after you'll do it - there's no need to have a reference of holiday in printHols(&holiday);

I've also added \n to printf but it's just for a better output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Date {
    char week_day[30];
    int day;
    int month;
};

struct Holiday {
    char name[80]; //name
    struct Date date; //date
};


void printHols(struct Holiday hol[]){
    printf("Holidays in 2018\n");

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        printf("%d / %d \t - %s \t - %s \n", hol[i].date.day, hol[i].date.month, hol[i].date.week_day, hol[i].name);
    }
}

void main(){
    struct Holiday holiday[] = {{"New Year",{"Monday",1,1}}, {"Some Holiday",{"Tuesday",2,3}} };

    printHols(holiday);
}
```